# React Native Pass param from function to class Component

Tags: android, ios, react-native, mobile

Can a param be pass to class from function ?

```
function generateListViewPager (category_id) {
    return () => {
        return (
            <View style={styles.pageContainer}>
                <ScrollView showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>
                    { <ListDataView value={category_id}/> } //Here
                </ScrollView>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

when I use {category_id} it say my mapping is error but when I set to "1" or {1} it works.

Comment: How do you call this function?

Comment: export const viewPage = generateListViewPager(1)

Comment: Try to call like this: generateListViewPager(1)();
because you are returning a function first and you need to run this returned function.

Comment: still error, if I wan to call viewPage from other page I already use viewPage()

Comment: Maybe the problem is about category_id type. İf the error is mapping error <ListDataView> might be need an array instead of just a number

Comment: Looks like I already found the problem, Its Cause by ViewPager showing number when index at 0 it show 1 and 2 pass value even I already set generateListViewPager(1)

Comment: Its good to you solve the problem